# parse nmap results string using python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x, nmap

Im automating nmap using python , i like to get some specific value from the results, which is a string

```
PORT    STATE SERVICE
443/tcp open  https
| ssl-cert: Subject: commonName=*.google.com/organizationName=Google LLC/stateOrProvinceName=California/countryName=US
| Subject Alternative Name: DNS:*.google.com, DNS:*.android.com, DNS:*.appengine.google.com, DNS:*.cloud.google.com, DNS:*.crowdsource.google.com, DNS:*.g.co, DNS:*.gcp.gvt2.com, DNS:*.gcpcdn.gvt1.com, DNS:*.ggpht.cn, DNS:*.gkecnapps.cn, DNS:*.google-analytics.com, DNS:*.google.ca, DNS:*.google.cl, DNS:*.google.co.in, DNS:*.google.co.jp, DNS:*.google.co.uk, DNS:*.google.com.ar, DNS:*.google.com.au, DNS:*.google.com.br, DNS:*.google.com.co, DNS:*.google.com.mx, DNS:*.google.com.tr, DNS:*.google.com.vn, DNS:*.google.de, DNS:*.google.es, DNS:*.google.fr, DNS:*.google.hu, DNS:*.google.it, DNS:*.google.nl, DNS:*.google.pl, DNS:*.google.pt, DNS:*.googleadapis.com, DNS:*.googleapis.cn, DNS:*.googlecnapps.cn, DNS:*.googlecommerce.com, DNS:*.googlevideo.com, DNS:*.gstatic.cn, DNS:*.gstatic.com, DNS:*.gstaticcnapps.cn, DNS:*.gvt1.com, DNS:*.gvt2.com, DNS:*.metric.gstatic.com, DNS:*.urchin.com, DNS:*.url.google.com, DNS:*.wear.gkecnapps.cn, DNS:*.youtube-nocookie.com, DNS:*.youtube.com, DNS:*.youtubeeducation.com, DNS:*.youtubekids.com, DNS:*.yt.be, DNS:*.ytimg.com, DNS:android.clients.google.com, DNS:android.com, DNS:developer.android.google.cn, DNS:developers.android.google.cn, DNS:g.co, DNS:ggpht.cn, DNS:gkecnapps.cn, DNS:goo.gl, DNS:google-analytics.com, DNS:google.com, DNS:googlecnapps.cn, DNS:googlecommerce.com, DNS:source.android.google.cn, DNS:urchin.com, DNS:www.goo.gl, DNS:youtu.be, DNS:youtube.com, DNS:youtubeeducation.com, DNS:youtubekids.com, DNS:yt.be
| Issuer: commonName=GTS CA 1O1/organizationName=Google Trust Services/countryName=US
| Public Key type: unknown
| Public Key bits: 256
| Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
| Not valid before: 2020-03-03T09:45:25
| Not valid after:  2020-05-26T09:45:25
| MD5:   bda3 4bfa 9f3d 5091 14a2 4a0e 992b 183f
|_SHA-1: 12b0 59d4 f6fb cd67 5013 a49e 44cf 053f d773 a07f
```

my method return issuer,public key and public key bit and signature algorithm but with the rest of string output

```
def run_command():
    command ="nmap -p 443 --script ssl-cert google.com"
    output = subprocess.getoutput(command)
    Issuer= output.split("Issuer: ",1)[1]
    public_key = output.split("Public Key type: ",1)[1]
    public_key_bit= output.split("Public Key bits: ",1)[1]
    singature_algor = output.split("Signature Algorithm: ",1)[1]
    print(Issuer,public_key,public_key_bit,singature_algor)
```

the wanted results, just to print the value of each of these values bellow

```
Issuer: commonName=GTS CA 1O1/organizationName=Google Trust Services/countryName=US
Public Key type: unknown
Public Key bits: 256
Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
```

Comment: What is the question? What have you tried? What result are you getting from the code you have?

Comment: i want to print the value of each of these : Issuer,Public Key type,Public Key bits and Signature Algorithm

Comment: why don't you use [python3-nmap](https://pypi.org/project/python3-nmap/)

Comment: I did try it but it doesn't support some nse scripts, check my other question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61098484/nmap-engine-failed-to-load-a-script

Answer (score 1):

I manage to find a way

```
    def verify_certificate(self,to_check):
        command ="nmap -p 443 --script ssl-cert google.com"
        output = subprocess.getoutput(command)
        line = re.findall(to_check+":.*$", output, re.MULTILINE)
        for x in line:
            results = x.split(to_check+":",1)[1]
            print(results)
```

output

```
commonName=GTS CA 1O1/organizationName=Google Trust Services/countryName=US
```

and by changing to_check value, I get the other values as well without duplicate code.